# launch a method present in third party DLL in a new appdomain

Tags: c#-4.0, appdomain

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DoCallBack
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New Domain");
            Console.WriteLine(newDomain.BaseDirectory);
            newDomain.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(SayHello));
            AppDomain.Unload(newDomain);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call SayHello() method in new application domain. Lets assume, HelloMethod DLL is third party and I dont have the code. I have only assembly. But I know it has SayHello() method. What can I do?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace HelloMethod
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }

        static void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi from " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
        }
    }
}
```

In this current code, its giving error "The name 'SayHello' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to load the assembly if it is not already loaded. Two ways to do that:

1. Reference the assembly from your project and simply do:

   ```
   newDomain.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(HelloMethod.Program.SayHello));
   ```

   this is ok if you don't mind referencing the third party assembly in your own project. This also means that you know at compile-time the assembly, type and method that you wish to call.
2. Load the third party assembly yourself and execute the specific method:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// To be executed in the new AppDomain using the AppDomain.DoCallBack method.
   /// </summary>
   static void GenericCallBack()
   {                       
       //These can be loaded from somewhere else like a configuration file.
       var thirdPartyAssemblyFileName = "ThirdParty.dll";
       var targetTypeFullName = "HelloMethod.Program";
       var targetMethodName = "SayHello";

       try
       {
           var thirdPartyAssembly = Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(thirdPartyAssemblyFileName));

           var targetType = thirdPartyAssembly.GetType(targetTypeFullName);

           var targetMethod = targetType.GetMethod(targetMethodName);

           //This will only work with a static method!           
           targetMethod.Invoke(null, null);             
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Callback failed. Error info:");
           Console.WriteLine(e);
       }
   }
   ```

   This could be used if you are looking for a more flexible way to call a public static method from a third party assembly. Note that pretty much everything is inside a try-catch since a lot of stuff can go wrong here. That's because each of these "Reflection" calls can throw exceptions. Finally **note** that for this approach to work is to have the third party assembly and all of its dependencies located in your application's base directory or in one of the private bin paths.

Comment: Thanks allot, **new CrossAppDomainDelegate** is necessary? Why we can run without this?

Comment: @SHRI It is necessary! The compiler generates code for each delegate type that you declare. The CrossAppDomainDelegate probably lets the compiler know that the delegate should be derived from MarshalByRefObject to allow for cross-AppDomain communication. This is my speculation though. The important thing is that you need to use CrossAppDomainDelegate.